# how to set rowcount to zero in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

anyone have an idea how to set rowcount to zero again in SQL.

I have used rowcount to fetch the number of records inserted in the insert statement. I have to use rowcount again to find the rows updated. So i am trying to reset the rowcount again to zero.

code will be look this :

```
INSERT INTO Table A ......

INSERT INTO statistics (id,inserted_records ) values (1,@@rowcount)
```

---some operations--

```
Update Table A ....

Update statistics set updated_records=@@rowcount where id=
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of programming language like c# or php? Then you should add this information to the question.

Comment: specify SET ROWCOUNT 0.

Comment: @Nagaraj: SET ROWCOUNT 0 does something different than wanted: "Causes SQL Server to stop processing the query after the specified number of rows are returned."

Answer (score 1):

```
 select @@rowcount
```

only returns the row count from the most recent statement. **It doesn't need to be reset.**. Executing another statement will automatically reset it.

If for some bizarre reason, you want to make `@@rowcount` return 0, execute a query that will return 0 rows.

```
select 1 where 2=3
```

You can prove this like so.

```
declare @t table (i int)
declare @stats table(rc int)

insert @t values (1),(2),(3)
-- rowcount is 3
insert @stats values (@@rowcount)
-- rowcount is 1
update @t set i=5 where i=4 
select @@ROWCOUNT -- rowcount will be 0
```

Comment: You should give the code example of how you are doing this.

Comment: This is a good idea, but am getting values as 1 after the update statement, even after no update  :( @podiluska

Comment: I accept that it will be zero, But after my update statement it becomes one,i donno how and why? If i need to set is as zero, like someone mentioned earlier, i can use a select statement which returns 0.

Comment: Per the documentation, @@ROWCOUNT will give you the rows affected during an operation, such as the entire run of a sproc.  I'm finding that, where I do two sets of updates within the same proc and thus getting double the value I'm looking for.  So it's not fair to say there is no reason to ever reset it.  In fact the documentation indicates you can do this so it was planned for.

Answer (score 1):

@bibinmatthew @@ROWCOUNT automatically resets whenever you do another transaction.

What I would consider doing is

```
declare @rowsAffected int
insert into table A ...
select @rowsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT

insert into table statistics (id, inserted_records) values (iID, @rowsAffected)

declare @rowsAffected int
update table A ... 
select @rowsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT

update table statistics set updated_records = @rowsAffected where id = iID
```

This way, you are not having to deal directly with the @@ROWCOUNT variable. I have created the @rowsAffected twice because I am assuming that you have the insert and the update scripts in different stored proc's

Answer (score 0):

Information about rowcount are here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms187316.aspx

> Statements such as USE, SET , DEALLOCATE CURSOR, CLOSE CURSOR,
>   BEGIN TRANSACTION or COMMIT TRANSACTION reset the ROWCOUNT value to 0

So maybe you can put the statements into a transaction, so they are better isolated against each other.

And you can always just send a request that does not update anything, like `UPDATE mytable SET x=1 WHERE 0=1;`